# rails devise undefined method username when I want to use it with cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, cancancan

I want to achieve a role based authorisation in rails. for login I use the gem devise, which works perfect. but after I am including some code of cancancan like in this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/cancancan-rails-authorization-dance/) I get an error undefined method username and when I remove username I get an error undefined method email...

here is my code:

ability.rb (to manage what a user with a specific role can do)

```
    class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

      user ||= User.new

     if user.role?(:admin)
       can :manage, :all
     elsif user.role?(:mitarbeiter)
       can :manage, :documents
       can :manage, :entries
     end

  end

end
```

a part of my user.rb

```
      ROLES = {0 => :admin, 1 => :mitarbeiter}

  attr_reader :role :

  def initialize(role_id = 0)
    @role = ROLES.has_key?(role_id) ? ROLES[role_id] : ROLES[0]

  end

  def role?(role_name)
    role == role_name
  end
```

a part of my application_controller.rb

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  check_authorization

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:warning] = exception.message
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def current_user
    User.new(session[:id])
  end

  helper_method :current_user
```

I really can't get whats wrong...
I thought that I have to set @user like @role in user.rb but it doesn't helped

Comment: Where is this error happening - you're not calling `username` anywhere in your question ?

Comment: ah oh sorry I call current_user.username in views. bevore I worked with cancancan it worked...

Comment: I don't think you should override `initialize` for ActiveRecord-derived models, at least not without calling `super` in them.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest removing the `User#initialize` method and `attr_reader :role` declaration and create own `role` method as follows:

```
def role
  @role ||= ROLES.has_key?(role_id) ? ROLES[role_id] : ROLES[0]
end

def role?(role_name)
  role == role_name
end
```

This way you achieve what you intended, but without overriding ActiveRecord's `User#initialize` method.

Above code assumes, that `role_id` is stored in database in `role_id` column.

Comment: I think need the initialize method to set what a role can or am I wrong here?

Comment: I get this error : undefined local variable or method `role_id'

Comment: Role for user has to be somehow stored? Do you store `role_id` in database?

Comment: no I got a "role" field in the users table but the roles arent stored in the database. is that a problem?

Comment: How do you know, which user have which role? What types od values can be inside `role` field (integers, strings)?

Comment: I mean I would like to store the role in the users table... but the roles above arent stored in a roles table (I think I don't need one)

Comment: You don't need special table to store users' roles. You need one column in users table. IMO numeric type `role_id` (or any other name), where you would store `0` when user is admin and `1` when user is mitarbeiter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that, And the role_id get stored in the database correctly too. here my solution:

my new ability.rb  (not finish only for testing functionality)

```
    class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

     user ||= User.new

     if user.has_role? :admin
       can :manage, :all
     elsif user.has_role? :mitarbeiter
       can :manage, :documents
       can :manage, :entries
     else
        can :read, :all
     end

  end

end
```

new user.rb

```
      ROLES = %i[admin mitarbeiter]

  def roles=(roles)
    roles = [*roles].map { |r| r.to_sym }
    self.role_id = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((role_id.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.include?(role)
  end
```

new application_controller.rb part

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, roles: [] ]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
```

here a I give the role to a user views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
    <% for role in User::ROLES %>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][#{role}]", role, @user.roles.include?(role), {:name => "user[roles][]"}%>
      <%= label_tag "user_roles_#{role}", role.to_s.humanize %><br />
    <% end %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", "" %>
```

I also removed some gem(paperclip, roo, rolify) that maybe were an issue
I got this in my Gemfile:

```
    gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'
    gem 'cancancan'
```